# intent filter which can used to listen mobile data enable and disable event

Tags: android, intentfilter

Actually In my app I have to show the toggle button on/off if mobile data packect on/off.

But there is a problem my local boradcast can't listen mobile data packet on/off event if my WiFi is already on. Actually as I understand If my WiFi on then mobile data packet enable and disable event never affect connectivity status. Thats why my some intent filter never works.

android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

I need a intent filter which is similer to android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED  so that whenever mobile data packet on or off event fire my broadcast can listen it easily. And I can change my widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know of any `intent-filter` that we could receive when the mobile data is turned on or off but the following code is to determine whether mobile data is turn on or off.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected())
    //mobile data is on
else 
    //mobile data is off
```

What you can do is write a service of your own that will constantly run the above code. When the mobile data is on, you can send a broadcast to your activity telling the same. Same goes when the mobile data is off.

**Edit1:-**
This works even if wi-fi is connected.

**Edit2:-** Don't forget to add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission while using this

Answer (score 0):

I think in your app,you need to import `WifiManager` Class.
`WifiManagerclass` provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. Get an instance of this class by calling
 `Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)`